# Explain the use of inverse

Tags: public-key, secp256k1

I understand that from private key `1` to `57896044618658097711785492504343953926418782139537452191302581570759080747168` every public key is literal inverse of private key `115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336`  to `57896044618658097711785492504343953926418782139537452191302581570759080747169` what i mean is  public key of private key `1` is `0279be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798` (also the G) and the inverse of 1 is `0379be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798` whos private key is `115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336`  what is the purpose of this? is it to perform point subtraction? and is this the only intent?. and another question, lets assume we have a the private key range and the target public key whos private key we know for a fact it lies within the known private key range, can we not use this inverse property?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Elliptic curves indeed have the property that the X coordinate of `k*G` equals the X coordinate of `(n-k)*G` (with `n` the curve order and `G` the generator). But this isn't on purpose - it's a mathematical property that elliptic curves have. They aren't chosen on purpose to have this property, but given that they do, it can be used.